# Code not executed without any error/module msg

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

My code was working well but after updating my Pydroid 3 Android app it stopped working...

```
from tabulate import tabulate
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def hist_pcr(Symbols):
    url = f"https://niftyinvest.com/put-call-ratio/{Symbols}"
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    # print(soup)
    result = []
    for data in soup.find_all("p"):
        text=data.get_text("|",strip=True)
        tokens=text.split("|")
        if(len(tokens)==6):
            result.append({'Date': tokens[1], 'Symbol': tokens[2].split()[0], 'LTP': tokens[3], 'PCR': tokens[5]})
    pcr_df1 = pd.DataFrame(result)
    pcr_df2 = pcr_df1.iloc[::-1].head(13)
    pcr_df = pcr_df2.reset_index(drop = True)
        
    return pcr_df    
    
Symbols = ["ACC"]                        
for symbol in Symbols:
    try:
        pcr_df = hist_pcr(symbol)
        print(tabulate(pcr_df.head(12), headers='keys', tablefmt="pretty"))
    except:
        pass
```

There is no any error or module msg I'm getting. What could be the reason plz .

Comment: `except: pass` means that if there is an error, do nothing

Comment: except Exception as e: print(e)  still no output nor any error

Comment: If you do not handle the error, you should not use a "try: except:" block

Comment: Have you any solution for my problem plz ??

Answer (score 1):

I ran your code in my machine. I see two import statements are missing.

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
```

Please add these import statements and try.

Comment: Already tried this but no output. Can you suggest something else or any way to search the glitch plz ??

Comment: change your exception handling code

```python

    except BaseException as e:
        print(e)

```

and look for what error do you see?

Comment: name 'requests' is not defined. Importing requests there is no output and code is running on with no program finished msg

Comment: Is your mobile data switched on? 

Request makes a HTTP network request via `requests.get(url)`. There might be a problem in this HTTP network request.

Comment: Yes ofcourse it's on. My other codes are running well

Comment: what phone are you using? Is there enough RAM to support this code or other apps are consuming all the ram.